# Is the union of the intersection the same as the intersection of the union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A_{nm}$ is a subset of $A$ for $n = 1,2, \dots$ and $m = 1,2, \dots$ is it necessarily true that

$$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Big[ \displaystyle\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty A_{nm} \Big] = \displaystyle\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \Big[ \displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_{nm} \Big] \, \, ? $$

---

I claim that this is the case. So I attempt to prove it by showing double inclusion which implies equality.

*Proof*.

Let $x \in \displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Big[ \displaystyle\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty A_{nm} \Big]$. By definition of union, there exists $\displaystyle\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty A_{n_0 m}$ so that $x \in \displaystyle\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty A_{n_0 m}$. By definition of intersection, we have

$$\forall \, m \in \mathbb{N}, x \in A_{n_0 m}$$

Now notice that  for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we also have $x \in A_{n_0 m} \subset \displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_{nm}$.

Now from here, I want to somehow get an intersection on the outside of that union to show inclusion the first direction, but I'm not sure how to do so. Maybe union and intersection *aren't* interchangeable. Maybe there's a counterexample to this claim. Any advice?

Comment: Suppose $A_{m,n}=\{1\}$ if $m=n$ and $A_{m,n}=\varnothing$ if $m\ne n$. What do the two sides of your identity turn out to be in that case?

Comment: Hint: even with the $\infty$s replaced by $2$s, you can find a counterexample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is false. For every $n$, let $A_{n1},A_{n2},\dots$ partition the entire space $X$ (so are disjoint). Then $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \Big[ \displaystyle\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty A_{nm} \Big] = \bigcup_{n=1} \emptyset=\emptyset$$

and

$$\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \Big[ \displaystyle\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_{nm} \Big]=\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty X=X$$

Comment: As noted in Greg Martin's comment, this can be done with $m$ and $n$ just ranging from 1 to 2. Just partition into two pieces for each $n$.